# Display nested data from Firebase in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

please help me with my code. I tried display retrieved data in my html table using javascript, but nothing work. I am new in firebase, if it possible please anyone help me or give advice, I have already tried everything methods on stack (

The structure of my base looks like this,please check the image from the link below

[/Notes/{Generated User Token}/{Generated Date}/{Generated Note ID}/Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ii0p.jpg)

My Html Code

```
<table style="width:100%" id="ex-table">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Name:</th>
 </table>
```

Javascript

```
var database = firebase.database();
    var uid = firebase.auth().uid; // Not working, How to get a path to Generated tokens? 
    var date = // How to get a path to "DateddMMyyyy" from a structure?
    var notes = // How to get a path to "NoteXXXXXXX" from a structure?

    database.ref().child('Notes' +token+ '/' +date+ '/' +notes+ '/' ).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.exists()){
            var content = '';
            snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                var val = data.val();
                content +='<tr>';
               content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#ex-table').append(content);
        }
    });
```

I do not know how to write a path to *Generated Date* "**DateddMMyyyy**" and *Generated Note ID* "**NoteXXXXXXX**"

> I need only display end fields from structure. What should I edit in
>   my code?

Ps: For more details about Generated date, please check code from android studio "**`timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());`**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the date formated id pass the input date to `getDateId` use it to construct the `database.ref()`

```js
function getDateId(dt){
    var date = new Date(dt);
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    if (currentMonth < 10) { currentMonth = '0' + currentMonth};
    if (currentDate < 10) { currentMonth = '0' + currentDate};
    return `Date${currentDate}${currentMonth}${date.getFullYear()}` 
}

var inputDate = new Date();
var dateId = getDateId(inputDate);

console.log(dateId)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with the date function !